# Converting CString to Char to Update Database

Tags: c++, mysql, c, cstring

I currently need to update a MYSQL database. The codes below is in the form CString. However Sprintf takes in char type. How do i exactly change/modify the variable S so i can update it into my database using the sprintf function.

Thanks, Jason

```
void CT1121Dlg::DisplayTagData(int cnt,int tag_len,int start_index)

{
MYSQL *pConnection;
MYSQL_RES *pResult=NULL; 
MYSQL_ROW Row;
char Query[256];

int fields;
pConnection = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(pConnection,"localhost","root","123","test",0,NULL,0); 


    CString s,s0;

    int i,j;

    unsigned char t;
    unsigned char t1;


    //unsigned char y[] ="";

    //string mystring;
    //unsigned char y;

    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {   
        s.Format("NO.%d: ",start_index+i+1);
        for(j = 0; j < tag_len; j++)
        {
            t = IdBuf[i].Ids[j];


            //sprintf(Query, "INSERT into t(e) values (%X)",y);
            if(t < 0x10)
            {
                s0.Format("0%X ",t); // if hexa is less than 10 print 0 infront of it


            }
            else
                s0.Format("%X ",t); // else just print the 2 bit hexa decimal


            s += s0;

        }


        sprintf(Query, "INSERT into t(e) values (%X)",s); // nt working
        //sprintf(Query, "INSERT into t(e) values (+ %s.c_str() +)",s); // cannot work
        if ( mysql_query(pConnection,Query) == 0 )
    {
        pResult = mysql_store_result( pConnection );    
        }

        AddOprationInfo(s);


    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `CString` over `std::string` and using the `std::string::c_str()` to get the char*

Comment: @111111: Yes, because `c_str` returns a `char const*` not a `char *` which `sprintf` needs.

Comment: @BillyONeal Why use sprintf at all?

Comment: @111111: When `CString::Format` is already there? No reason at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CString::Format` instead, just as you did earlier in that method. (Though I would suggest not using `CString` at all in favor of `std::string`...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CString::GetBuffer()` method to get the pointer to a null terminated internal buffer of a `CString`.

Comment: +1 because this will make the code compile. But I don't think this is what the OP should do.